# How to programmatically add UITabBarItem's Identifier type in iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I want to add UITabBarItem in programmatically in iOS.

In interface Builder,we can easily choose with Identifier for Search,Favourites,Recent Tabs,etc..

I would like to know how can i add these Identifier type in programatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You add it as a UIViewController's property?
You create a `UITabBarItem`

`UITabBarItem *localTabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc]
                    initWithTitle:@"Date" image:clockIcon tag:0];`

And then set UIViewController's property

```
[viewController setTabBarItem:localTabBarItem];
```

Here is a huge pack of TabBar images http://www.axialis.com/objects/ip_icon_09.shtml

Comment: How do i add second BarButton in oneViewController?Thanks for answers.

Comment: What do you mean by secondbar button?second tab?

Comment: If i was right, you just create a tabbarcontroller and give it an array of viewcontrollers in the right order **UITabBarController *mvc = [[UITabBarController alloc]init];** **mvc.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:firstVC,secondVC,thirdVC, nil];**

Comment: Yes second tabBarItem in OneViewController.

Answer (score 3):

```
UITabBarItem *barItem = [[UITabBarItem] alloc] initWithTabBarSystemItem:UITabBarSystemItemMore tag:0];
self.tabBarItem = [barItem autorelease]; //of not using ARC
```

The predefined system bar items are:

```
UITabBarSystemItemMore,
UITabBarSystemItemFavorites,
UITabBarSystemItemFeatured,
UITabBarSystemItemTopRated,
UITabBarSystemItemRecents,
UITabBarSystemItemContacts,
UITabBarSystemItemHistory,
UITabBarSystemItemBookmarks,
UITabBarSystemItemSearch,
UITabBarSystemItemDownloads,
UITabBarSystemItemMostRecent,
UITabBarSystemItemMostViewed
```